# How to use Laravel 5.3 subdomain routing?

Tags: xampp, subdomain, laravel-5.3

I have a webpage accessible by ***localhost/example*** with a homepage with a company sign up area. Upon submitting that form, the page should redirect to ***localhost/register.example*** but I'm getting an error instead.

```
URL: register.example (the localhost is missing?)
*This site can’t be reached. register.example's server DNS address could not be found.*
```

**web.php** Route file

```
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@homepage');

Route::group( ['domain' => 'register.example'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'AccountController@register',
        'as' => 'companyregister'
    ]);
});
```

I have also changed my **config/session.php**'s line to

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'example'),
```

I've been looking everywhere but Laracasts' lesson on this one is not available for free. I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: I have this feeling that you have a .net background. I don't seem to understand what you what to achieve with `['domain' => 'register.ezloans']`.

Comment: @OniyaDaniel ezloans was supposed to be **example** domain sorry. I changed  it just now.

Comment: @OniyaDaniel I was following this docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Answer (score 1):

If your home page is at **localhost/example** that means the `/example` directory is where all your laravel files are kept.
When you are using **xamp** and the likes, creating sub-domains is another ball game (could be very tricky sometimes).

To give you an illustration, assume you have a domain already: **http://example.com**
Its sub-domain will be http://register.example.com

So, in your own case (**xamp**), your domain is **http://localhost**,
Its sub-domain will be http://register.localhost
(Sadly, I don't know how to set it up in the local environment)

What you are trying to do is *Sending post data from your main domain to its sub-domain*, which I believe should be handled with an api call.

So I'll advice you to try working with simple routing before going for the sub-domain thingy. Try redirecting your homepage to `http://localhost/example/register` instead.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@homepage');
Route::get('/register', [
    'uses' => 'AccountController@register',
    'as' => 'companyregister'
]);
```

Comment: I've decided on that one too to get this started. Thanks for your time! :)